# redirect HTTP POST apache,

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a problem where I want to get the parameter HTTP POST from another server, I want to communicate from server A to server B via HTTP POST, in this problem server A is using default software to POST to server B,. but server B cannot get request HTTP POST from server A, if I look at the access.log

```
"POST http://mywebsite/class/param" 404
```

that's mean, request from server A not recognized, 404 page not found,. I then simulate using html form uses method POST to get a correct log, if I look access.log again,

```
"POST /class/param" 200
```

200 mean OK, request acceptable,.

My question is how to redirect POST

```
http://mywebsite/class/param
```

to

```
/class/param
```

?? I've tried to searching, seemed to be able to use mod_rewrite, but I still can not use it.

spec:
server web : apache
web language: php
php framework : codeigniter

Comment: Well, exists and php extension name `curl` that could be useful for you. This is a [good example](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for reply manix, but my problem is cannot retrieve POST from server A,

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite POST requests, the content body won't be included so you'll lose your POST params. What you need to do is change what is sending this request so that it's sending the proper URI. It looks like it may be something as simple as the action being `http://mywebsite/http://mywebsite/class/param` and it just needs the host removed.

Comment: Yes, may be a mistake setting in server A to enter the appropriate URI., but if I simulate using action in html form `http://mywebsite/http://mywebsite/class/param` in access.log will show `POST "/http://mywebsite/class/param" 404` looks little different with result access.log from server A. I've been contact with the admin server A, he's claim URI same with I requested. What should I do?

Comment: @panji If there isn't a leading slash, that means someone is using your server as a proxy server. Either way, there's no way to correct this using mod_rewrite, you need to fix the source of the problem.